# Error: Accounts: Cannot specify any additional fields when marrying or separating a Person-Account

Tags: upsert

I'm using an ETL tool Talend for data push to salesforce. When I'm upserting the accounts getting the error below In the mapping I specified the business accounts recordtypeId but still is throwing the same error.

1.What is the cause for the error?

2.Do I need to add anything else other than the recordtypeId to differentiate the Business Accounts and person Accounts?

**Error:**

```
Exception in component tSalesforceOutput_1
java.lang.Exception: Cannot specify any additional fields when marrying or separating a Person-Account

at org.talend.salesforce.SforceManagementImpl.upsert(SforceManagementImpl.java:481)
at salesforceetl.sync_accounts_0_1.sync_accounts.tMysqlInput_1Process(sync_accounts.java:2841)
at salesforceetl.sync_accounts_0_1.sync_accounts$2.run(sync_accounts.java:19166)
ERROR: export_salesforce_client -> Accounts: Cannot specify any additional fields when marrying or separating a Person-Account
-- null records rejected. Please check error log file workspace/log/sync_salesforce.sync_accounts.loaderrors.log
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When changing record types from business to person you cannot specify any other field values.

I believe what is happening is that you are trying to populate the record type of a BUSINESS account with the value of the Person account record type along with the other fields and this is not allowed.

Or alternately you are trying to change a person account of one record type ID to another person account record type ID...

Basically the change of the recordType ID cannot include any other field values

Comment: I made sure that no mappings to the person account fields. Also I have hardcoded the business account Recordtype Id. But still getting the same error I think the issue is the Name field that I'm using to map the Account Name. If I try to remove the Name from mapping it say the required field name is missing. I made no access to consumer record type to API user still same error. Is there a way to stop this person accounts?

Comment: @SalesforceLearner - Can you post a few line of the csv as well as the operation you are trying to perform?

Comment: @ Eric:Thanks a lot. I got the issue I'm trying to update a person account with the business account fields so that makes the records to fail.